# Can't get Apache to load the HomeBrew version of PHP

Tags: php, apache, homebrew

The published wisdom for getting this to work is to edit the LoadModule call in httpdf.conf. So I've tried pointing httpd.conf at the Brew loaded PHP. I've changed the LoadModule line from:

LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so

to:

LoadModule php7_module /usr⁩/local/⁨Cellar/⁨php@7.3⁩/7.3.26_1⁩/lib⁩/⁨httpd⁩/modules/libphp7.so

I then tried apachectl restart, but when I do this, Apache doesn't complain, it just fails to start! Am I pointing it at the wrong thing, or is this totally the wrong approach?
I am running Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) under Mojave.
The brew caveats say add **this** too httpd.conf

```
 LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

When I do this, Apache fails to start. If I leave httpd.conf alone it loads PHP Version 7.1.33, which is not what I'm trying to achieve!

I'm at a total loss :(

Comment: Any error on the apache log files? You may also start apache from shell to see the output .

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I had the PATH wrong. The path I had set was:

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

which meant that when I loaded apache it didn't use what brew had installed.
I stopped apache, then changed the path to:

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

then after **apachctl restart** it loaded everything from the correct place and phpinfo() now shows the correct version of php.